# Hans's corenlp-summarizer in Java(Stanford CoreNLP)

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

> I have error with his code from https://github.com/hans/corenlp-summarizer. How can i add a file to run this code. I try to run it but it have error like this picture [image]
>
> ```
> package bao;
> ```

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.stats.ClassicCounter;
import edu.stanford.nlp.stats.Counter;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.PropertiesUtils;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;


public class Summarizer {

 private static final StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;
 static {
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos");
props.setProperty("tokenize.language", "es");
props.setProperty("pos.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");

pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
   }

 private final Counter<String> dfCounter;
 private final int numDocuments;

public Summarizer(Counter<String> dfCounter) {
this.dfCounter = dfCounter;
this.numDocuments = (int) dfCounter.getCount("__all__");
 }

 private static Counter<String> getTermFrequencies(List<CoreMap> sentences)   {
Counter<String> ret = new ClassicCounter<String>();

for (CoreMap sentence : sentences)
  for (CoreLabel cl : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class))
    ret.incrementCount(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class));

return ret;
 }

 private class SentenceComparator implements Comparator<CoreMap> {
private final Counter<String> termFrequencies;

public SentenceComparator(Counter<String> termFrequencies) {
  this.termFrequencies = termFrequencies;
   }

@Override
public int compare(CoreMap o1, CoreMap o2) {
  return (int) Math.round(score(o2) - score(o1));
   }

/**
 * Compute sentence score (higher is better).
 */
private double score(CoreMap sentence) {
  double tfidf = tfIDFWeights(sentence);

  // Weight by position of sentence in document
  int index = sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.SentenceIndexAnnotation.class);
  double indexWeight = 5.0 / index;

  return indexWeight * tfidf * 100;
  }

   private double tfIDFWeights(CoreMap sentence) {
  double total = 0;
  for (CoreLabel cl : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class))
    if   (cl.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class).startsWith("n"))
      total += tfIDFWeight(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class));

  return total;
   }

private double tfIDFWeight(String word) {
  if (dfCounter.getCount(word) == 0)
    return 0;

  double tf = 1 + Math.log(termFrequencies.getCount(word));
  double idf = Math.log(numDocuments / (1 + dfCounter.getCount(word)));
  return tf * idf;
    }
 }

 private List<CoreMap> rankSentences(List<CoreMap> sentences, Counter<String> tfs)   {
Collections.sort(sentences, new SentenceComparator(tfs));
return sentences;
 }

public String summarize(String document, int numSentences) {
Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(document);
List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

Counter<String> tfs = getTermFrequencies(sentences);
sentences = rankSentences(sentences, tfs);

StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < numSentences; i++) {
  ret.append(sentences.get(i));
  ret.append(" ");
   }

return ret.toString();
 }

  private static final String DF_COUNTER_PATH = "df-counts.ser";

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static Counter<String> loadDfCounter(String path)
throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
return (Counter<String>) ois.readObject();
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  //day nay phai them 1 file name nua moi du, tim xem cai file nay la      format the nao
  // o dau a ạ
  //doc source code, tim tren google xem thang nay no co viet paper voi cai tool nay ko hoac la doc ky la cai tutorial luc nay anh gui

  String filename = args[0];
 String content = IOUtils.slurpFile(filename);

Counter<String> dfCounter = loadDfCounter(DF_COUNTER_PATH);

Summarizer summarizer = new Summarizer(dfCounter);
String result = summarizer.summarize(content, 2);

System.out.println(result);
  }

  }
```

> > > > This is code of Hans
> > > >
> > > > ### Quoted Heading
>
> I don't know how to put the input file into this code like this:
>    
>     *`String filename = args[0];-`*

Comment: Please post the code and error, screenshots are not helpful.

Comment: Code is so long. His code is from my link

Comment: His code ? .. The screenshot does not show the full error message .."unrecoverable error while load... "??

Comment: Yes, I want to run his code in my data.

Comment: @Sid you can see this code in my link because it have two file. It is so long code to post here

Comment: Posting the error stack trace will help in finding out what the problem is. As it stands, the screenshot does not show what line the error is occuring on

Comment: I have just post this code

Comment: what is the content/purpose of the file df-counts.ser